# docker-compose keycloak with mysql server throws error

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I am trying to write a `docker-compose.yml` to setup Keycloak with a MySQL database. My file `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "1"

services:    
  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    container_name: "keycloak"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080/tcp
    command:
      - start-dev
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=changeme
      #- KC_HOSTNAME=http://localhost:8080
      - KC_DB=mysql
      - KC_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloak
      - KC_DB_USERNAME=keycloak
      - KC_DB_PASSWORD=changeme
    networks:
      - internal
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: "service_started"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'keycloak'
      MYSQL_USER: 'keycloak'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'changeme'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'changeme'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - internal

networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mysql_data:
```

But when Keycloak starts it throws the error

```java
WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (JPA Startup Thread) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

If anyone has an Idea why that happens I would be thankful for help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `KC_DB_URL` is not correct.

> KC_DB_URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/keycloak

`localhost` here is pointing to Keycloak container itself instead of MySQL container.

Update it to

```java
jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/keycloak
```

(use container name as DNS entry)

Comment: Hi thanks for the respose @jsxqf but this did not fix it. Do you have another idea?

Comment: @Staudi are you seeing the same error?

Comment: Try setting the healthcheck for the mysql database and setup the “depends_on: mysql: condition : service_heatlhy”

Comment: @Ratul Sharker thank you for your help. It worked